# Make glide animation from border of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an animation with a button with JS when the button is shown. The user is scrolling and when the screen scroll reaches 20px, the button is shown. While showing, I want the button to glide to a certain part of the screen, where it will be placed until it is hidden. This is the JS and HTML:

```js
var to_top_button = document.getElementById("to-top-button");

window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        to_top_button.style.display = "block";
        to_top_button.style.transition = "all 90s";
    }else{
        to_top_button.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 500px;
}

#to-top-button{
  display: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 5vw;
    width: 5vw;
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 88%;
    bottom: 3vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
    border-radius: 4vw;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
  <button onclick="to_top()" id="to-top-button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</body>
```

So as you can see, when the page is scrolled, the button is shown. I want to do an animation for when the button is shown, I want it to glide from the right border of the screen every time it is shown, but I don't know how to make animations on JS.

How can I make it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want you first need to position your button out of the screen to the right. You can achieve this by manipulating the right property in css.

```
right: -5vw;
```

When you reach the desired scoll position, change the value you want.

```
right: 5vw;
```

The full code will be.

```
<style>
    body {
        height: 10000px;
    }

    #to-top-button {
        height: 5vw;
        width: 5vw;
        background: yellow;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 3vw;
        right: -5vw;
        font-size: 3vw;
        border-radius: 4vw;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 50;
    }
</style>


function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                to_top_button.style.right = "5vw";
                to_top_button.style.transition = "all 1s";
            } else {
                to_top_button.style.right = "-5vw";
            }
        }
```